# How to disable MayhaveTenant filter for super admin(Host)?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I have a form where the list of data will shown.
The entity contains IMayhaveTenant Property.

Now when we created the record by admin user (Host), then we created the tenant first and after that assigned tenant Id into the same entity.

After that when we get the list of records, then those records have tenant id, not showing in the list. But when login with the tenant user then it shown under tenant login.

Now if we want to get the all list for host user then we disabled the IMayhaveTenant filter, then this works fine. But every time when we access the entity then we have to need disabled the IMayhaveTenant filter.

Now our requirement is when we logged in through host user then IMayhaveTenant filter will be set as default disabled, and when logged in with tenant user then it will work as it is.
Can you please advice for the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class for the AppService, then derive your application services from this class.

In the constructor of the base class, you can check whether the currently logged-in user is a host user with an admin role and then disable the IMayhaveTenant filter.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Derive your application services from this class.
/// </summary>
public abstract class AppNameAppServiceBase : ApplicationService
{
    public TenantManager TenantManager { get; set; }

    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    protected AppNameAppServiceBase()
    {
        if (!AbpSession.TenantId.HasValue &&
                UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(UserManager.GetUserById(AbpSession.GetUserId()),
                                                 StaticRoleNames.Host.Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant);
        }
    }
}
```